# addExitDescription(...) method on ExitStatus, but description is final

Tags: spring-batch

I tried to modify JobExecution ExitStatus description with its method :

```
addExitDescription(String description)
```

It does not work fine...

Maybe because the 'description' field is final in **ExitStatus** class :

```
private final String exitDescription;
```

(Spring Batch version: 3.0.3)

*Is there really a bug, or... should i get more coffee ?*

Thx in advance for your enlightments

Comment: Code should be formatted as code, but not as blockquote

Answer (score 3):

You need more coffee ;)

`exitDescription` is final, but that's addressed by the fact that `ExitStatus#addExitDescription(String description)` isn't a setter.  It creates a new instance of `ExitStatus` and returns it to you.  If you want to modify the `ExitStatus` on a `JobExecution`, you need to create a new `ExitStatus` and set it on the `JobExecution`.

Comment: So true !
Say 2 coffees more.

Such a functionnal way to do the job...

Thx for your quick response, Michael